# How to write perl one liner in Make?

Tags: perl, makefile

I am writing the following command to extract the text in makefile:-

```
@awk '/Exported Layer/,/Total Polygons/' out_compare.err | perl -lane '$el=$F[3] if(/Exported Layer/); print "$el: $f[3]" if (/Total Polygons/);' | cat
```

But it is giving the following error:-

Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment at -e line 1, near "] if"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Would you guys like to suggest something? :-)

Comment: works for me... Why pipe it to cat? Can you you add out_compare.err (stuff between exported layer and total polygons) Version of perl?

Comment: From where you executed : command line or makefile?

Comment: Replace `perl` with `echo` and see how it's getting mangled?

Comment: PS - `$f[3]` should be `$F[3]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make is oblivious to shell quoting in commands, so the `$` characters in your Perl snippet are being interpreted as make variables `$e` and `$F`.  These variables don't exist in your makefile and are being expanded as empty, leading to the Perl syntax errors you're seeing.

You need to escape the `$` characters from make like this:

```
... perl -lane '$$el=$$F[3] if(/Exported Layer/); ...
```

See also [the GNU Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Reference.html).